# How to loop a principled texture?

Tags: animation, texturing, materials, node-editor

How do I seamlessly loop a principled texture setup?

I've imported a gold material on a frame, and I want it to rotate clockwise. I tried animating the rotation value on the mapping node, and it looked fantastic, but I couldn't get it to loop; after animating the rotation from 0 to 360 it would start to rotate counterclockwise after a while.

I also tried linking the texture coordinate node to an empty bound to a circle, so that it could rotate, but it didn't move the texture one bit, I am sure I am doing something wrong but i don't know what.

[image: Frame]
[image]

Comment: hello could you please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MneI6CgZBr9Tz07aLTk93F7hDiraKM56/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you shouldn't let us ask for permission....

Comment: ups, my bad, sorry https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MneI6CgZBr9Tz07aLTk93F7hDiraKM56/view?usp=sharing

Comment: do you mean that the frame looks like a whole board and delete a rectangle in the middle?

Comment: nope, when i try to loop the texture rotating clockwise, after a while it starts going the other way around, and I can't manage to loop it

Comment: it's the rotation values of the Mapping that are taken into account and you've set 0° for frame 0 and 15° for frame 121, so how is it supposed to loop? The Texture Coordinate doesn't take the empty into account as you use the UV output

Comment: 0 to 15 was a just a test, to see what speed my client liked, changing 15 to 360 didn't loop the animation.. also, what output should i use instead of uv?

Comment: 0-15,it looks ok, they all rotate the same way and don't changed, I don't know what you mean.If 360 makes trouble,you should upload that file.

Comment: 0 to 360 works fine for me, not 0-15, it's a weird rotation though, as it is on the 3 axis

Comment: Here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JMn1sYqRKKNektGJ6QSu7xhjqcRFLOxN/view?usp=sharing also, the bottom piece of the frame is a separate object

Comment: @moonboots so for you it just loops? doesn't it distort and rotate in any strange way? if so, is there some setting that am i missing or something to do to fix it?

Comment: it loops but the animation is weird as it is on 3 axis. Maybe you should precise what kind of animation you'd like? So that we propose solution...

Comment: @moonboots I'll be honest, I don't really know, I just want it to rotate clockwise, and to look somewhat like the 0-15 animation

Comment: do you want something like that? https://zupimages.net/up/22/13/so5z.gif

Comment: @moonboots Yes, exactly

Answer (score 6):

The keyframe is wrong.From UV map,we can see that rotate the map will not lead a continue movement,but if we move the map along axis-y,it works.So the keyframe should add to location y.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! it looks good, but what can i do to make it loop?

Comment: UV map is 1m in height.Your bottom frame UV is opppsite to the others,so just set location from 1 to 0 for bottom frame and set location from 0 to 1 for other 3 frames.

Answer (score 4):

Edit: So it is basically the same answer as NatureK except I unwrap again so that the texture partially join.

Your frame is made of 3 different parts. First merge them all in one object with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>. In *Edit* mode, select all and merge by distance with <kbd>M</kbd>. Remove the seams with a <kbd>U</kbd>. Select a face then select all and unwrap with <kbd>U</kbd> > *Follow Active Quads*. Maybe you'll have to *Unwrap > Reset*. Scale the UVs in the *UV Editor* if needed:

[image]

Remove the rotation keyframes you've created for the *Mapping* node. Instead create 2 keyframes on Y, here is what it should give. If you want a linear animation, press <kbd>T</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, and your time. could you please please give me the file? I'm doing something wrong again and I don't have much time.. with the file i think I could understand better

Comment: Sure, here it is, I've merged the 3 objects to make one: https://we.tl/t-Vqg46tkJlc

Comment: thank you so much, you have been so helpful to me, much appreciated!